# How do i insert a new line character(\n) at the first line of a file?

Tags: bash, command-line

This is for mac osx terminal
Say i have a file lets say
    file.txt

```
This is a file  
and it has some contents.
```

i need a command to change it to:
file.txt

```
(new line character inserted)      
This is a file  
and it has some contents
```

Comment: Are you only trying to do this for one file? If so, why not open the file in a text editor, Press enter on the first line, and save the file?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For future reference, quality questions here include YOUR ATTEMPT to solve this problem yourself. Please have a look at the SO documentation - [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to create an example of your programming problem, and [How-To-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a more comprehensive guide to asking good questions.

Comment: I am not doing it for only 1 file.I am using nodejs's exec module to append a new line to a file.The file that i want to add a new line is given at run time with a grunt watcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done entirely within bash, no need to use external tools like `sed` or `cat`.

```
printf '\n%s' "$(< file.txt)"
```

Note that this prints the modified output to "stdout". It also strips any trailing newlines in your input file. If that's a problem, you're back to `cat`...

```
( printf '\n'; cat file.txt )
```

Heck, you could make it a function if you're going to re-use it a lot:

```
prepend_newline() {
    printf '\n'; cat "$1"
}
```

If you want to replace the original file, you could use a temporary file and a bit of wrapper:

```
tmpf=$(mktemp fileXXXX)
trap "rm -f $tmpf" 0
printf '\n%s' "$(< file.txt)" > $tmpf &&
mv $tmpf file.txt
```

Of course, this also negates the benefit of "no external tools" since `mktemp`, `rm` and `mv` are not built in to bash.

A more portable sed-based solution might look like this:

```
sed -i.bak $'1s/^/\\\n/' file.txt
```

Rather than relying on sed to be able to expand the `\n`, the solution above uses bash "format expansion" to add the newline with a method that works on other sed variants as well.

As was suggested in comments, `-i` is not universal, only widespread. If your sed does not include `-i`, see the wrapper above.

Comment: Though the `printf` solutions would lose the new line terminating the final line of the file, if any.

Comment: `sed -i` is not portable.

Comment: @EricRenouf - `printf '%s'` will indeed drop the trailing newline, but because of the `$(...)`, not because of the printf. It's easy enough to add a trailing `\n` if the OP wants it, of course.

Comment: It won't just drop *one* trailing newline, it will drop *all* trailing newlines.

Comment: @chepner, true, but I thought that was only historical. My impression is that it's more widespread than formatting characters in the replacement string. Can you enlighten me? What operating systems ship with a sed that doesn't support `-i`?

Comment: Tried your portable sed solution and it worked except for the fact that it ended up created a .bak file so i ended up using this commad:  
        sed -i '' $'1s/^/\\\n/' file.txt

Comment: Murphy's Law: you *can* ship a `sed` that doesn't support `-i`, so assume that someone, someday, will try this answer with such a `sed`. I'm not saying it's a bad suggestion, just that calling it portable is incorrect.

Comment: @chepner - re trailing newlines, hmm, that's true. Updated. And as for sed, updated to "more portable".  :-D  (Who needs absolutes?!)

Comment: @AnanthaPadmanaban - Great, I'm glad I could help! If you feel that this wraps up your issue satisfactorily, please feel free to click the checkmark on the left side of the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ed` on osx for this:

```
printf '%s\n' 0a "" . w | ed -s file
```

Comment: Not just OS X .. I think `ed` is everywhere, and has been forever. :)

Comment: `ed` is part of POSIX; this is probably the best answer. (Unless someone posts a variation using `ex -c` that doesn't require a pipe...)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is use two commands:

```
{ printf '\n'; cat input.txt; } > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt input.txt
```

This is slight less efficient than it could be, but it is correct in all corner cases.

Comment: Does "all corner cases" include writing through a symlink?  Then it's only correct if you define "correct" to mean "creates a new file in place of the link".

Comment: I should have known saying "all" would come back to bite me. Symlinks are a bit of a pain in this case; even `sed -i` (at least the BSD version I checked) will create a new file instead of updating the linked file in-place.

Answer (score 0):

Injecting inline with `sed` does this:

```
sed -i '1s/^/\n/' file.txt
```

Comment: This works for GNU sed, but it's not portable to other variants.

Comment: @ghoti That’s correct. It should also be noted that `sed -i` requires write permission on the parent directory rather than the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `ed` command to prepend a blank line looks like

```
1i  # insert before line 1
    # blank line to insert
.   # end of insert
w   # write the file
```

This can be written in a Bash command as

```
ed -s "$file" <<<$'1i\n\n.\nw'
```

Answer (score -2):

```
echo -e "\n$(cat file.txt)" > file.txt
```

However, as @EricRenouf stated, if there are other escape sequences in the file they would be expanded.

Comment: This would also expand any escape sequences in the file, whic might not be desired.

Comment: Also, with the redirect in that place you would likely just end up with `\n` in the file, since the redirection will happen first, truncating the file and the `cat` will have no output to work on.  This might work as is if `echo` is a builtin and not an executable though

Comment: Could you elaborate on your first comment? I get an empty line at the start of a text document and not \n.

Comment: Put `\t` in a text file and try that.

Comment: @EricRenouf The command substitution will complete before the redirection is processed, so that is not a concern.

Comment: @chepner Thank you very much for that clarification